# VB.net Linq Select Distinct

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using a Linq query on a DataTable in VB and I want to only bring back the unique Form names and GUIDs from a list of 5 items:
[image: Full list of data being queried]

I added .Distinct to my query however it is still bringing back the duplicate results as seen in the image.

```
Dim qry = (
  From d In Data 
  Where d("FormGUID").ToString IsNot "" 
  Select New With {
    .FormName = d("Form").ToString, #
    .FormGUID = d("FormGUID").ToString}
).Distinct
```

How do I only select the 2 distinct rows?

Comment: `.Take(2)` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2) might be of help. Remove the `.Distict` and then put `qry.Distinct.Take(2)` may help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic) - Equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types#equality)

> Equality
>
> Instances of anonymous types can be equal only if they are instances
>   of the same anonymous type. The compiler treats two instances as
>   instances of the same type if they meet the following conditions:
>
> - They are declared in the same assembly.
> - Their properties have the same names, the same inferred types, and are declared in the same order. Name comparisons are not
>     case-sensitive.
> - The same properties in each are marked as key properties.
> - At least one property in each declaration is a key property.
>
> **An instance of an anonymous types that has no key properties is equal
>   only to itself.**

So to allow for proper equality testing, make your anonymous type's fields `Key`*ied*.

```
Dim qry = (
  From d In Data 
  Where d("FormGUID").ToString IsNot "" 
  Select New With {
    Key .FormName = d("Form").ToString, 
    Key .FormGUID = d("FormGUID").ToString}
).Distinct
```